# Entity Framework: Why do navigation properties disappear after a group by?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I retrieve a collection with the following query:

```
var numbers = _betDetailItem.GetBetDetailItems().Where(betDetailItem => betDetailItem.BetDetail.Bet.DateDrawing == resultToCreate.Date && betDetailItem.BetDetail.Bet.Status == 1).Where(condition);
```

Right there I'm able to access my navigation properties and navigate through binded info. Note how I actually use them to filter the data.

After I group the results, the navigation properties become null.

```
var grouped = numbers.GroupBy(p => p.BetDetail.Bet);
//Iterate through the collection created by the Grouping
foreach (IGrouping<Bet, BetDetailItem> group in grouped)
{
    var details = group.Key.BetDetails; //This is what doesn't work. BetDetails is a navigation property which was accessible in the previous query. 
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: They don't. Something else is going on here which isn't in your post. Try a simple query against Northwind without all your custom code. If you can't get that to work, post it here.

Comment: Why can't this work like every other ORM?

Comment: As I said, I think your question is based on a false premise. Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: I did a GroupBy against NorthWind on LinqPad, and got the result I expected. The problem is not the grouping. The problem are the navigation properties of the grouped elements.

Comment: If it works on Northwind, but not your model, I think we need to see more of the code that you're talking about -- what properties you can access on 'numbers', what you mean by "binded info" and what you get after grouping.

Comment: I added what I do after... So you can see what's happening exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing LINQ to Entities and object operations.

This is LINQ to Entities:

```
var numbers = _betDetailItem.GetBetDetailItems().Where(betDetailItem => betDetailItem.BetDetail.Bet.DateDrawing == resultToCreate.Date && betDetailItem.BetDetail.Bet.Status == 1).Where(condition);
```

So is this:

```
var grouped = numbers.GroupBy(p => p.BetDetail.Bet);
```

These are object operations:

```
foreach (IGrouping<Bet, BetDetailItem> group in grouped)
{
    var details = group.Key.BetDetails; //This is what doesn't work. BetDetails is a navigation property which was accessible in the previous query. 
}
```

In LINQ to Entities, there is never any need to think about loading related instances. You can always refer to any property of any object. However, at some point, you want to move out of the LINQ to Entities world and into object space, because you want to work with instances of type `BetDetail` instead of type `IQueryable<BetDetail>`. This means that the Entity Framework is now required to generate SQL to retrieve data from the database. At that point, it doesn't snow which related instances you will be accessing in your code later on. Nothing in your LINQ to Entities query forces the loading of the related `Bet`. So unless you do something to cause it to be loaded, like use eager loading, explicit loading, or EF 4 lazy loading, it won't be loaded.

Using lazy loading (e.g., in Entity Framework 4, or in another ORM) will make this code *appear* to function, but it will be unnecessarily slow, due to the large number of database queries generated. A better solution would be to use [eager loading](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/07/migrating-from-linq-to-sql-to-entity-framework-eager-loading.aspx) or [projection](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/). This way there will be only one DB roundtrip.

Comment: Links to eager loading and projection are stale.

Answer (score 1):

Once you do a `GroupBy()`, you're no longer dealing with your entities -- they have been... well, grouped, so the `var` in `var grouped = ...` is now of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<...`. As such, the methods available on the items in the `grouped` collection are the methods of the `IGrouping<>` interface.

You may want to `OrderBy()` instead of `GroupBy()`, depending on your need, or you'll need to iterate on two levels: iterate over each group in `grouped`, and over each member within each of those.

Once you are inside of a particular `IGrouping<>`, you should have access to the properties for which you are looking.